# Относительный импорт в Python 3

Tags: python

Имеется пакет Trio

```
Trio\  
    __init__.py  
    Funk.py  
    StartPy.py
```

пытаюсь из файл StartPy **ОТНОСИТЕЛЬНО ИМПОРТИРОВАТЬ** Funk

```
from . import Funk
```

Но выдаёт ошибку

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Funk' from '__main__' (D:\My_Import\Trio\StartPy.py)
```

Не знаю что делать. Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Импорт на самом деле работает.

Дело в том, что Вы пытаетесь запускать этот файл. Как бы странно это не звучало, но Вы не должны этого делать. Если Вы создаёте пакет, то основной модуль программы должен быть за его пределами.

---

Вот [выдержка из документации](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) по этому поводу:

> Note that relative imports are based on the name of the current
>   module. Since the name of the main module is always `"__main__"`,
>   modules intended for use as the main module of a Python application
>   must always use absolute imports.

*Вольный перевод:*

> Обратите внимание, что относительный импорт основан на имени текущего
>   модуля. Поскольку имя основного модуля всегда `"__main__"`, модули,
>   предназначенные для использования в качестве основного модуля
>   приложения Python, всегда должны использовать абсолютный импорт.

---

То есть, Ваш код верный, и всё, что требуется, - создать модуль за пределами пакета и запускать уже его. Использовать пакет при этом можно, ошибок не будет.

---

**UPD:**

Думаю, стоит немного пояснить такое поведение.

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что, при запуске модуля Python, его имя - `__main__`, соответственно, относительный импорт будет производиться относительно `__main__`, а не пакета, в котором он находится.
Конечно, это бред, поэтому ничего не получится.

Когда мы обращаемся к модулю в пакете из модуля за пределами пакета, то имя модуля в пакете будет `Trio.[имя модуля]` и относительный импорт внутри модуля пакета будет производиться относительно `Trio`, то есть относительно этого пакета.

---

Проверить это довольно легко с помощью инструкции `print(__name__)`. Допустим, мы добавили её в `Funk.py`, после чего создали модуль за пределами пакета `Trio` и выполнили в нём инструкцию `from Trio import StartPy`. Напечатается `Trio.Funk`, что и требовалось доказать.

Comment: «основной модуль программы должен быть за его пределами» — во-первых, можно положить `__main__.py` внутрь пакета; во-вторых, можно запускать как `python -m Trio.StartPy` и импорт тоже будет нормально работать