# Проблема с импортом из текущей директории

Tags: python

Стараюсь изучить импорт модулей `python`. Но недавно столкнулся с проблемой при импорте модуля из текущей директории. Директория выглядит так:

```
- source.py
- src.py
```

В файле `src.py` хранятся данные, которые я собираюсь собирать оттуда в файле `source.py`. Я пишу:

```
from . import src
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
  from . import src
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

В чём ошибка? Что я делаю не так?

Comment: рядом с ```src.py``` есть  ```__init__.py```?

Comment: Как писали выше проверьте наличие файла `__init__.py`. Он указывает что данная директория является пакетом а не просто папкой с файлами.

Comment: Просто `import src` работает?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Относительный импорт в Python 3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/998951/1365)

Answer (score 3):

Вкратце: замените `from . import src` на `import src`.

Импорт через точку - это относительный импорт. Относительный импорт работает только внутри пакетов, при этом такой импорт будет работать только если `source.py` импортирован из пакета, а не запущен или импортирован как отдельный модуль. К примеру, имеем такую структуру файлов:

```
+-module.py
+-sources
  +-source.py
  +-src.py
```

Директория `sources` при этом является пакетом, несмотря на отсутствие файла `__init__.py` (начиная с Python 3.3 его наличие стало необязательным, см. [PEP 420 -- Implicit Namespace Packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/)).

Дальше:

- В модуле `module.py` одна строка: `from sources.source import *`
- В `source.py` одна строка: `from . import src`
- В `src.py`: `print("Hello from src.py!")`

Запускаем: `python3 module.py`

Вывод: `Hello from src.py!`

Если перейти в `sources` и запустить `python3 source.py`, то будет такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../sources/source.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import src
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Перевод - "попытка относительного импорта при неизвестном родительском пакете". Аналогичная ошибка будет, если попытаться импортировать source.py напрямую с помощью `import source`.

---

Таким образом, у вас два варианта:

- вынести ваши файлы в пакет, тогда можно будет использовать относительный импорт (придется его использовать импорта для модулей в этом же пакете, т.е. импорт вида `import src` или `from src import ...` из модуля того же пакета работать не будет)
- либо не выносить в пакет, и использовать обычный абсолютный импорт.

Comment: если в `source.py` прописать `import src` все будет работать без ошибок. И можно запускать `python source.py`

Comment: @Kers, естественно будет, но вопрос был именно про использование относительного импорта.

Comment: А если нужно импортировать файл выше на один или более уровней?

Comment: @Flark ставить несколько точек (две точки - один уровень выше, и т.д.), но может быть проще путь в PYTHONPATH добавить.

Comment: Да, но вся проблема в том, что имея файл в директории *`package1\package2\module2.py`* с кодом *`from .. import module1`*, в программе, пытаясь импортировать файл *`package1\module1`* в файл *`package1\package2\module2`*, возникает ошибка *`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`*. Как использовать конструкцию from ..+ import <module>?

Comment: Значит у вам package1 с точки зрения интерпертатора не пакет, а просто папка. Если у вас там главный модуль лежит, который вы запускаете просто как python имя_файла.py, то вы не сможете из этой папки импортировать что-то относительным импортом из пакетов в этой папке.

Answer (score 0):

Дополню немного.
В Вашем случае просто не используйте относительный импорт через
`from . import src`
а замените его на:
`import src`

P.S. И да наличие файлов `__init__.py` желательно но не обязательно.